# Definition of irreducible - inclusive or exclusive or?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I just met the definition of an irreducible element:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $a \in R$.

> We say that a is irreducible if the following all hold:
>
> - $a \neq 0$
> - $a \notin R^*$
> - $a=bc$ for $b,c \in R \Rightarrow$ $b$ or $c$ is a unit

I was wondering whether the third condition is an inclusive or i.e. could it be that both $b$ and $c$ are units?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If both $b$ and $c$ are units, $a$ is a unit as well, so it is covered by the second bullet point. But it really does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any author ever writes something where they mean exclusive or, but don't specify that it is exclusive, that would be considered at best a typo, and at worst misleading. "Or", by itself, should always mean inclusive or.

In this particular case, however, it doesn't matter, as both of them being units breaks the second point.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! I'm assuming the 'product of two units is a unit' is a well known fact? Also I assume that for the third condition of the definition of a prime element: 'if $p|ab$ for some $a,b \in R$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$', we have the exclusive or too?

Comment: @MathsicalStudies If $a = bc$ with $b, c$ units, then $ac^{-1}b^{-1} = 1$, so $a$ is a unit. And yes, it's the same for prime, as otherwise $p^2$ would always be a counterwitness to $p$ being prime, as $p\mid a$ _and_ $p\mid b$ with $a = b = p$, and so no element would ever be prime.